# Where is a proof that string field theory is generally covariant?

Tags: covariance, diffeomorphism-invariance, string-field-theory

Given a space-time coordinate of a string $X^\mu(\sigma)$ dependent on the position $\sigma$ around the string. And a string field functional $\Phi[X]$, is there a proof that the equations of motion (or the action) are generally covariant. ie. invariant under a transform $X^\mu(\sigma) \rightarrow Y^\mu(X(\sigma))$ ?

All I have seen are talks about $X^\mu(\sigma)$ being diffeomorphically invariant under a change of string coordinates $X^\mu(\sigma)\rightarrow X^\mu(f(\sigma))$. But that isn't the same thing.